# How to return a matchCollection from function in Visual Basic, Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to return a matchCollection from a function to be able to loop through my matches and write them to excel cells outside the function.

I get the run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set, when my code comes to:

If matches1.Count <> 0 Then

This is my code:

```
Sub simpleRegex()

  Dim ShortRange As range
  Set ShortRange = ActiveSheet.range("A2:A505")
  Dim strInput1 As String
  Dim matches1 As MatchCollection

  For Each cell In ShortRange

    strInput1 = cell.Value

    Set matches1 = CheckMatch(strInput1)

    If matches1.Count <> 0 Then
        cell(1, 3).Value = matches1(0).SubMatches(2)
        cell(1, 4).Value = matches1(0).SubMatches(3)
    End If

  Next

End Sub

Public Function CheckMatch(str As String) As MatchCollection

  Dim strPattern1 As String
  Dim strInput As String

  Dim regEx As New RegExp
  Dim matches As MatchCollection
  Dim Match As Boolean

  Match = False


  strPattern1 = "((storlek|strl|stl|strlk|storleken|storl|size|storleksmärkt|storl|storlk|st).{0,2}?(?:[^\s]+)?.{0,2}?)?(30|32|34|36|38|40|42|44|46|48|50).?(30|32|34|36|38|40|42|44|46|48|50)?"

   strInput = str

   With regEx
     .Global = True
     .MultiLine = False
     .IgnoreCase = True
     .Pattern = strPattern1
   End With

   If regEx.test(strInput) Then
     Match = True
     Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
   End If

   Set CheckMatch = matches

End Function
```

Anyone who knows how this can be fixed?

Comment: If there is no match, then the matchCollection is not initiated. Only if it enters in your If regEx.test(strInput) Then

Comment: Besides, you have declared `matches1` and then use `matches(0)`

Comment: There is a match, the code is entering If regEx.test(strInput). Yes thats right Wiktor, my bad. However, it does not solve the problem of getting in to the loop in the first place..

Comment: I simplified your code a bit, and after fixing the matches it works. Tried with your updated code: it works well if you just pass a string (not a range).

Comment: Is it possible to get all the sub matches with a string? I would like to gather the sub matches in different cells in excel.

Comment: Sorry, your question is off-topic now and unclear.

Comment: Yes, it got a bit confusing. My question simply was if it is possible to return a matchCollection from a function but the answer to that question might be no. I'm trying to get around my problem in a different way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If this is VB.NET then your use of the `Set` keyword is not valid and should be removed. If this is VBA then you should tag your question as such instead of VB.NET.